# Getting query output from ogr2ogr?

Tags: postgis, sql, ogr2ogr

I want to get SQL command from ogr2ogr. My og2ogr command is:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=sa dbname=name password=secpsw" commm.dbf -nln "commision"
```

and i want it as like this:

```
MyOgr2ogr command > output.sql
```

ogr2ogr result is SQL commnand, which insert Dbf file to PostGIS. But I get not this SQL command. SQL command is hidden and I wanto to show it

For example shp2pgsql command produce SQL command and i can use shp2psql > insert.sql

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a bit more detail about what exactly you're trying to do, and what happens when you try it.